# Keep toggle state on divs using cookie.js after page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple code which allows me to toggle betwen two divs which are wraps for two sub navigations (#sub-nav-wrap is the alternative nav). They are fixed to the bottom of the browser :

```
$(function(){
$('.button').click(function(){
    $('#sub-nav-wrapmin').toggle();
    $('#sub-nav-wrap').toggle();
  });   
});
```

What I wish to do is to keep the state of each div the same as chosen by the user after page refresh and even if the clicks on a new sub-heading the menu will remain the same, rather then resorting to the default state.

The html is this:

```
<!--- Main Sub Wrap --->
<div id="bottom-wrap">
<!-- Mini Sub Nav -->

<div id="sub-nav-wrapmin" class="snWrap divone">
        <div id="sn-contentmin">
            <div id="sn-likemin"></div> 
            <div id="sn-coffeesml"></div>
            <div id="sn-sharemin"></div>
            <div id="sn-commentsml"></div>
            <div id="toggle-barmin">
                    <div id="sn-sidebrdrmin"></div>
                    <div class="sn-toggle button"></div>
           </div>
              <ul class="sn-comicsmin menu">
                <li><a class="sn-comics" style="background-position: right top" href="#comic.html">Comic</a></li>
                <li><a class="sn-archive" href="#archive.html">Archive</a></li>
                <li><a class="sn-vote" href="#vote.html">Vote</a></li>
                <li><a class="sn-spotlight" href="#spotlight.html">Spotlight</a></li>
            </ul>
      </div>
</div>
<!-- Sub Nav -->
<div id="sub-nav-wrap" class="snWrap divtwo">
    <div id="sub-nav-container">
         <div id="sub-nav-content">

                <div id="sn-bnrlft"></div>
                <div id="sn-bnrrgt"></div>
                <div class="sn-dividelft"></div>
                <div class="sn-dividergt"></div>
                <div id="sn-likebg"></div>
                <div id="sn-coffeebtn">
                </div>
                <div id="sn-sharebtn"></div>
                <div id="sn-commentbtn"></div>    
                <div id="toggle-bar">
                    <div id="sn-sidebrdr"></div>
                    <div class="toggle button"></div>
                </div>            
        </div>
        <div id="sub-nav-brdr">
            <ul class="sub-nav-comics menu">
                <li><a class="comics" style="background-position: right top" href="#comic.html">Comic</a></li>
                <li><a class="archive" href="#archive.html">Archive</a></li>
                <li><a class="vote" href="#vote.html">Vote</a></li>
                <li><a class="spotlight" href="#spotlight.html">Spotlight</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS is this:

```
#sub-nav-wrap {
    display: none;  
}
```

This is my first time asking, and I have been wracking my brains to get this to work using other similar codes from this site, but nothing is working.
Please help...

Comment: Can we see what you have tried?

Comment: Please make fiddle on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Hello Raminson and Kir I have constructed a jsFiddle here to show how the  navigation works without a cookie: http://jsfiddle.net/replacement4/nKFt7/60/

Comment: This is my attempt using cookies: http://jsfiddle.net/replacement4/nvf3V/3/ I hope it is something simple and I've just miss understood...

Answer (score 2):

you're almost done everything right only have written a lot of superfluous :)

```
$(function(){
    if($.cookie('submin_visible') == 'true') {
        $('#sub-nav-wrapmin').show();
        $('#sub-nav-wrap').hide();
    } else {
        $('#sub-nav-wrapmin').hide();
        $('#sub-nav-wrap').show();
    }

    $('.button').click(function(){
        $('#sub-nav-wrapmin').toggle();
        $('#sub-nav-wrap').toggle();

        var isVisible = $('#sub-nav-wrapmin').is(':visible').toString();
        $.cookie('submin_visible', isVisible);
    });
});
```

Comment: Please close the question otherwise it is listed as unanswered

Comment: How do I close the question properly?