# Remember toggle state on div after page refresh

Tags: jquery, cookies

I have a div that expands/collapses to an automatic height based on button clicks. I have that working just fine, but I would like to use jquery.cookie.js to remember if the user expanded it or not, so that it stays open on page refresh.  I've looked at similar questions

e.g. [Keep toggle state on divs using cookie.js after page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11700513/keep-toggle-state-on-divs-using-cookie-js-after-page-refresh)

however I can't seem to get this to work for my situation. It's not just a straight show/hide, and I'm having trouble figuring out the syntax to properly set and use the cookie. Here is a fiddle of my working code, perhaps someone can help me?

http://jsfiddle.net/j2Rsy/

and here is the relevant code:

```
$('#viewless').hide();
$('#viewmore').click(function(){
    var el = $('#resize01'),
    curHeight = el.height(),
    autoHeight = el.css('height', 'auto').height();
    el.height(curHeight).animate({height: autoHeight}, 500);
    $('#viewmore').toggle();
    $('#viewless').toggle();
});

$('#viewless').click(function(){
$('#resize01').animate({height: '190'}, 500);
    $('#viewmore').toggle();
    $('#viewless').toggle();
});
```

Comment: I find localStorage easier and less code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
$('#viewless').hide();
$('#viewmore').click(function(){
    var el = $('#resize01'),
        curHeight = el.height(),
        autoHeight = el.css('height', 'auto').height();
    el.height(curHeight).animate({height: autoHeight}, 500);
    $('#viewmore').hide();
    $('#viewless').show();

    $.cookie('viewmore', true);

});

$('#viewless').click(function(){
    $('#resize01').animate({height: '190'}, 500);
    $('#viewmore').show();
    $('#viewless').hide();

    $.cookie('viewmore', false);
});

if($.cookie('viewmore') == 'true'){
    $('#viewmore').click();
} else {
    $('#viewless').click();
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yjxzQ/)

Comment: This works! So, if I understand correctly, you are just initiating the click functions that are already established?

Comment: Thank you very much, jQuery (and javascript in general) is still very new to me.  I appreciate it.

Comment: hey there @Arun P Johny do you have any idea how can I apply something similar in my situation please? thanks http://stackoverflow.com/q/32687806/4642215